# Inserting a figure after a numbered element

Tags: floats, positioning, theorems

The following code produces a figure at the top of the page, and a heading 'Example 1.1.2.' just below the figure. How can it be done to place the heading above the figure?

Have also tried with `\begin{figure}[hbt!]`, same result.

```
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}

...

\newpage
\begin{example}
\begin{figure}
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, every fit/.style={text width=2cm},->,]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\endminipage \hfill
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
\end{example}

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want a float to float the easiest solution is to not use a float. You can use `\captionof{figure}{...}` to produce a caption of the kind `figure` outside of a `figure` environment. `\captionof` is provided by the KOMA classes (those starting with `scr`), the `capt-of` package and the `caption` package. If you still want to use a `figure` environment, you could try to specify its placement with `\begin{figure}[htbp]` which allows to place the figure where it is in code (but doesn't guarantee it). Another solution would be to use the `H` placement (continued)

Comment: (continued) The `H` placement is provided by the `float` package. It works by not using a floating environment internally (so is somewhat the same as my first proposal). You then don't need the `\captionof` macro.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more on the not using a float thingy: You could for example use something like `\par\vspace{\intextsep}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}<content>\captionof{figure}{<caption>}\end{minipage}\par\vspace{\intextsep}`.

Comment: @Skillmon `\begin{figure}[htbp]` produced the same result. As for the 3rd solution, I fail to see how to implement it, could you please provide a solution based on this? The current class is set to `\documentclass[20pt]{extbook}`.

Comment: `\documentclass[20pt]{extbook}\usepackage{float}\begin{document}\begin{figure}[H]<content>\caption{<caption>}\end{figure}\end{document}` though I personally like the `\captionof` solution provided by @A.Ellet more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you can use `\captionof` to label the figure without it being a float.  LaTeX is the float master, not you: meaning, you don't get much say in the where and how of float placement.  So, if you have a figure you want in a particular spot, don't use a float.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{example}
~\par\addvspace{1ex}%%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, every fit/.style={text width=2cm},->,]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (10,-6);
  \node[scale=2.5] at (5,-3) {\bfseries\sffamily THIS IS MY FIGURE};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{MY FIGURE CAPTION}
\end{minipage}
\end{example}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

LaTeX will let you get away with writing `\minipage` and `\endminipage`.  But this is not how it was designed to be used.  The proper syntax is `\begin{minipage}` and `\end{minipage}`.  I don't see the need for the `minipage` environment here though maybe you have more going on than you've presented here.

Comment: Works nicely. As for the `minipage` syntax, agreed, now it's updated (it's used to divide the figure into three figures).